# In PSQL how can i insert a date with year month day hour minute and seconds in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sql-update

I have trie this, but is gives ERROR:  invalid value "03/12" for "MON"
`update verificationcodes set date =TO_DATE('2023-03-12 23:10:25','YYYY-mon-DD hh24:mi:ss') where id = 68;`

can somebody solve this?

i was expecting to work

Comment: `YYYY-mon-DD` should be `YYYY-MM-DD`: https://dbfiddle.uk/TWHaCvNp

Comment: The Postgres datatype `date` does not contain time. You will need datatype `timestamp`  or `timestamptz`. See documentation [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). Tnen use function `to_timestamp()` rather than `to_date()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in Oracle SQL, which I think will work in Postgres as well.

```
select to_date('12/07/2022 07:08:38 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') dates
```

-- edited to remove 'from dual' as suggested by Stefanov.sm